# DataFormat.Error on AssignedTo column running Power BI query to get Azure DevOps data

Tags: azure-devops, powerbi, odata

I'm using [this sample Power BI query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/sample-boards-directlinks?view=azure-devops&tabs=powerbi#sample-queries) to get data from Azure DevOps Services, and I get the following error on the **AssignedTo** column:

> DataFormat.Error: We expected a property 'AssignedTo', but the OData service omitted it from the response data. This can occur for a number of reasons and does not necessarily imply that the data does not exist or is of a default value. Details:
> Property=AssignedTo

However, if I run the URL directly in a browser, I get all the data returned correctly including the **AssignedTo** column.

Any idea what might be happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing `OmitValues = ODataOmitValues.Nulls` from the query fixed it. It appears that the sample query assumes there are only non-null values, and will therefore omit null values. Removing this part of the query ensures that null values are considered valid, and therefore removes the error.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when the AssignedTo is empty in Azure DevOps. The solution is to replace it with empty:

```
    #"Replaced Errors" = Table.ReplaceErrorValues(#"Your table here", {{"AssignedTo", ""}})
in
    #"Replaced Errors"
```

Comment: Thanks, but I had a suggestion from a Power BI Support Engineer from Microsoft to remove `OmitValues = ODataOmitValues.Nulls` from the query, and this solved it better. Your solution would be useful if null was indeed an error, but in my case they are valid values. I've posted my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67870391/197591).